# how to get xml node by type?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, html-parsing

I have this xml:

```
<html>
<head><title>504 Gateway Time-out</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

how can I get this text?

504 Gateway Time-out. nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)

I have tried writing xml parser, but I'm not sure how to select node by its type?

```
@Override
public String getProp(String prop) {
    String answer = null;
    try {
        final Document document = loadXMLFromString();
        Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
        answer = root.getElementsByTagName(prop).item(0).getTextContent();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return answer;
}

private Document loadXMLFromString() throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource is = new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString));
    return builder.parse(is);
}
```

Comment: That's not XML, it's HTML. You won't be able to parse it with an XML parser. (The `<hr>` tag is not closed, which is fine in HTML but not in XML.) Try a HTML parser (i.e. jsoup.org).

Comment: can you use xpath in java?